# Floats and overflow-x: hidden;

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the rest of a box, if it is beyond the containers width *(100% in the actual code)*. The elements are floating.

However, it throws them to the next line instead of hiding the remaining part of it.

Here is the example I made for demonstrating the problem.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>

    <!-- Just for showing the pink box -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 180px;
    background-color: pink;

    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper .box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    float: left;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bLaxyvwb/2/

Comment: [Drop `float`, use `inline-block` instead](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bLaxyvwb/3/).

Comment: maybe a dirty fix.. but if you set the height of the wrapper to 50px - it will be exactly what you want ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLaxyvwb/7/) with the changes you need to apply.

Use the following CSS:

```
.wrapper{
 width: 180px;
 background-color: pink;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper .box {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

And the HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
</div>
```

I did the following:

- Added white-space: nowrap to .wrapper
- Removed float:left; from .wrapper .box
- Added display: inline-block; to .wrapper .box

Comment: +1 You'll either need to get rid of the whitespace between each `div` or add `font-size: 0;` to `.wrapper` to get rid of the extra spaces caused by using `display: inline-block;` http://jsfiddle.net/w02wecr0/